# Accessing specific ports in Azure VM

Tags: azure

I have an application that must access the VM on specific ports: 8161 and 9161. For that I have registered that ports as endpoints in Azure Portal, logged in to the VM and added the inbound rules to let the Firewall pass the traffic. The VM has a public IP.

Now, I can access the virtual machine with:

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 8161
```

but I can't with

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 9161
```

`netstat -an` outputs the port 8161 as listening but 9161 is not visible.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Below you will find a screenshot from the WireShark.

[image: WireShark screenshot: Two packets targeting 9161 and 8161 port]

Comment: It sounds like there's nothing listening on port 9161 on the VM.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've set up to listen on the inbound ports. It would also be helpful to know which ports you mapped the external ports to. Right now, you're only providing a small bit of information.